# Solve "Weighted Activity Selection" problems with OptaPlanner

Tags: optimization, selection, scheduling, optaplanner, planning

We want to plan activities for tourists by selecting some (around 10) for a day from a large set (around 10K) of available ones according to likes, dislikes, etc. I think it belongs to the "[Weighted Activity Selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_selection_problem#Weighted_Activity_Selection_Problem)" class of problems.

(1) is it possible to solve that with OptaPlanner?
(2) how should we do it?
(3) can you refer relevant documentation?

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely possible to solve this with OptaPlanner, but in my opinion, this wouldn't really be optimal: OptaPlanner tries to solve NP-hard problems using various heuristics - essentially, it purges the search space in one way or the other. It is very improbable that it actually finds the absolute global maximum (or minimum) - although it does probably get quite close.

As far as I can tell, this problem isn't NP-hard and therefore could be solved in polynomial time `O(n^k)` where `k` is constant.

*There are also pseudo-polynomial algorithms, which might also be the case here - the complexity is then dependent on the weight and input size. For example `O(w*n^k)` where `w` is the biggest weight.*

In this case, you would probably be better off going with a dynamic programming solution, as described in the wiki article [you linked to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_selection_problem#Weighted_Activity_Selection_Problem). Also, don't forget to introduce some sort of randomization into the weights, or you will always deterministically pick the same set of "best" activities for a given day and a given group of tourists.

Some math to sum it all up:

- 10K activities isn't large at all. Everything you need per activity is: the start time, end time and weight.

  - If all these were 32bit integers and you made a Java object, the needed memory is (approximately) `3*4B + 8B (object overhead) = 20B/object`, which is `200 000B` in total, i.e. `~195kB`.
- If you implemented the suggested `O(n^3)` dynamic programming algorithm, the running time with 10K activities would be **approximately** `10 000^3 / 10^9 (1GHz processor) = 1000 seconds ~ 17 minutes`. This is a very crude estimate. Also, the `O(n log n)` algorithm would plow through data of this size (using the same estimation) in `132 ns`.